# Background video in div full responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, background

I'm searching to put a video in backgrund of a div (contact and footer div). It's work on my full screen, but in mobile is not.

My html is:

```
<div class="header-unit">
    <div id="video-container">
            <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth" >
                    <source src="videos/video_contactme.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
                    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
           <h1>...</h1>
           <p>some contents</p
    </div>
</div>
```

and my css is:

```
    .header-unit {
    height: auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#video-container {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size:cover
}
```

So, how can i put it responsive for mobile and imac 27inch too ? (i'm ussing bootstrap)

Answer (score -1):

This will get you part of the way there: http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video

Your main problem will be device orientation. Desktops are horizontal and portrait mobile is vertical... But the intrinsic ratio will get you closer to obtaining the scale you're looking for.

Comment: That article was written 7 years ago. Other things that happened in 2009: Michael Jackson died, Avatar was released and swine flu was a 'problem'.

Comment: Thanks DickieBoy, super helpful